# Do smart pointers preclude the need for two-phase construction?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, c++11, destructor

Two-phase construction takes the following shape:

```
struct something {
    something ()
      : p1(NULL)
      , p2(NULL)
    {   }

    ~something () {
        if (p1) delete p1;
        if (p2) delete p2;
    }

    void initialize () {
        p1 = new int(2);
        p2 = new int(5);    // May throw if allocation fails!
    }

    int* p1;
    int* p2;
};
```

The point of which being that a naive constructor (that doesn't watch for allocation failures) will leak memory: a partially-constructed object's destructor is never called.

My question: is the following code safe, and by corrolary, do smart pointers obviate two-phase construction?

```
struct something {
    something ()
      : p1(new int(2))
      , p2(new int(5))
    {   }

    std::unique_ptr<int> p1;
    std::unique_ptr<int> p2;
};
```

Comment: You don't need a conditional before `delete`. Seriously, you don't.  Deleting null is perfectly fine.

Comment: There're non-throwing new and delete too that work with memory allocation much like malloc()/free(). But even if the allocation itself doesn't fail using non-throwing new/delete, object constructors may still throw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your new code is fine. Note however that there is a possible subtly in more complex cases:

```
#include <memory>

struct foo {
  foo(std::shared_ptr<int> a, std::shared_ptr<int> b) { }
};

struct bar {
  foo f;
  bar() : f(std::shared_ptr<int>(new int), std::shared_ptr<int>(new int)) { }
};

int main() {
  bar b;
}
```

would not be safe however since the order of evaluation of the arguments of the constructor of `foo` in the initializer list of `bar` is unspecified. A conforming compiler might choose to do a depth or breadth first order of evaluation (or anything else so long as they all got evaluated correctly in the end). This means that if the first `new int` succeeded, but the second one throws before the `shared_ptr` objects got constructed the first allocation to be performed could still leak.

If you find yourself wanting to do this there are two possible solutions, besides just falling back to two-phase construction: the first might be a refactor, the second would be to construct the `shared_ptr`s individually first as members of bar, before `f`. Which of those is most appropriate is a judgment call I think needs to be made on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 5):

> My question: is the following code safe,

Yes, that would be OK.

```
struct something {
    something ()
      : p(new int(5))
    {   }

    std::unique_ptr<int> p;
};
```

Note that the naive code

```
struct something {
    something ()
      : p(new int(5))
    {   }

    int* p;
};
```

would be exception safe, too, because there's only one allocation which can fail. I think you're talking rather about

```
struct something {
    something ()
      : p(new int(5)), q(new int)
    {   }

    int *p, *q;
};
```

which wouldn't. Smart pointers would work in that case, too.

Comment: Ay, you're totally right; I have updated the example to actually trigger the leak.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two phase construction at all if you simply handle the exception.  This is the RIAA way.

```
struct something {
    something ()
      : p1(NULL)
      , p2(NULL)
    {   
        p1 = new int(2);
        try {
            p2 = new int(5);    // May throw if allocation fails!
        } catch (std::bad_alloc&) {
            delete p1;  //cleanup 
            throw;  //rethrow
        }
    }

    ~something () {
        delete p1;
        delete p2;
    }

    int* p1;
    int* p2;
};
```

Comment: If I'm not completely mistaken, this is explicitly **not** the RAII way, because you first **initialise** `p1` with `NULL`, and **later allocate** a `new int(2)`.

Comment: This makes `something` fulfill RAII, though it's internals do not fulfill RIAA.  When you delve far enough into the internals of any RIAA class, eventually you _will_ get to a class who's internals do not fulfill RIAA.  My point was the exception safety and lack of two-phase initiation.  `unique_ptr` doesn't have RIAA members either.